# Update subscriber status at publication list level within a BU using Fuel SDK

Tags: soap-api

We have requirement to be able to update (Subscribe / Unsubscribe) Subscriber Status at specific Publication list level within a BU. We are using Java Fuel SDK for this. The API Key / client secret has been generated at the BU level. 
Following is the API code;

ETClient client = new ETClient();

```
   ETFilter filter = new ETFilter();
   String[] props = {"ID","PartnerKey","CreatedDate","ModifiedDate","Client.ID","Client.PartnerClientKey","ListName","Description","Category","Type","CustomerKey","ListClassification","AutomatedEmail.ID"};
   filter.setProperties(new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(props)));
   ETExpression e = new ETExpression();
   e.setProperty("ID");
   e.setOperator(Operator.EQUALS);
   e.setValue("891647");
  filter.setExpression(e);

   Class<ETList> type = ETList.class;

   ETResponse<ETList> y = ETList.retrieve(client,type, null, null, filter);
   for (ETList folder : y.getObjects()) {
       System.out.println(folder);


   }
```

891647 is the MID for the specific publication list.

However, the above ends up unsubscribing the subscriber from the BU level and not just from the publication list level. Is there anything else we need to do for this?